# Example for the Sobolev embedding theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

We know that $W^{k,p}\hookrightarrow C^{k-\lfloor\frac{n}{p}\rfloor-1,\gamma}(\bar{\Omega})$ with $kp>n,\gamma=\lfloor\frac{n}{p}\rfloor+1-\frac{n}{p}$, where $n$ is the dimension of $\Omega$, $\Omega$ is a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $C^1$ boundary.
From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality#Sobolev_embedding_theorem). This can also be seen in C.L.Evan's "*Partial Differential Equations*".

However, when $n/p$ is an integer, the theorem does not state anything more about $\gamma=1$. Is there any counterexample to 
$W^{k,p}\hookrightarrow C^{k-\frac{n}{p}-1,1}(\bar{\Omega})$ when $n/p$ is an integer? I don't know how to construct it, Thanks for your attention!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function can be constructed using natural log functions. The intuition is that sometimes a function involving natural log can be integrated around the origin, but the function itself or its partial derivative shows highly singular behavior around the origin.

The following example might work (checked using wolframalpha, someone please correct if wrong): Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$, $u\in W^{2,2}(\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is a disk of radius $1/2$ centered at the origin. Let $$u(x,y) = \frac{x-y}{\sqrt{-\ln(x^2+y^2)}}$$
Using only the Laplacian for computing the 2-seminorm we have 
$$\|u\|^2_{W^{2,2}(\Omega)} = \|u\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} + \|\nabla u\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} + \|\Delta u\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}<\infty$$
But 
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = -\frac{x (x-y)}{(x^2+y^2) \sqrt{-\ln(x^2+y^2)}} + \frac{1}{ \sqrt{-\ln(x^2+y^2)}}
$$
goes to infinity near the origin.